# Is it possible to rank wireless networks?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

When using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, is it possible to rank, in order of preference, which wireless network one's computer should connect to first, second, etc?

Comment: Yes you can. See the "priority'" option at the wireless settings

Comment: What application are you referring to?  WiFi RADAR?

Comment: No. The ubuntu I use uses network manager. Ill make an answer when I am at my system ;-) It is explained here: https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
nmcli connection modify wdn connection.autoconnect-priority 10
```

On my system that makes it:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ nmcli -f autoconnect-priority,name c 
AUTOCONNECT-PRIORITY  NAME              
5                     schijfwereld-2.4g 
10                    schijfwereld-5g   
-999                  UTP               
10                    wdn
```

A higher numbers gets a higher priority.

Depending on the Ubuntu release and flavour

```
nm-connection-editor
```

Connection Editor allows you to set  automatic connection with a priority level (from the general tab)