# How to set wlan higher prioriy than ethernet in ubuntu?

Tags: networking, internet, cron, ethernet

I'm having a PC having Ubuntu 16.04. Internet works perfectly when connected to wlan, but as soon as I connect my PC to Ethernet, it automatically switches to Ethernet and my internet stops working.

I want my default network priority to be wlan.

I've tried giving lower metric to wlan using ifmetric, and it works but when I restart my system again the priority get sets to default.

command: sudo ifmetric wlan0 100

I have tried running ifmetric command on startup using crontab, but my sudo doesn't get execute since sudo needs password.

how to run ifmetric command without sudo or is there any other way to set wlan as my default network in Linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to rank wireless networks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100338/is-it-possible-to-rank-wireless-networks)

Comment: @NGRhodes Not a duplicate of that. Here questioner want to set priorities of ethernet and WLAN not among different WLAN connections.

Answer (score 5):

Open `terminal` and start `nm-connection-editor`, open your wireless connection profile, then edit the following highlighted field, enable it, and set it to 1.

[image]