# Need Ubuntu 20.04 WiFi Connection at Power On

Tags: networking

I am deploying a small fleet of laptops with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop to remote sites to do a specific job. The remote sites are all unique, and wired ethernet connections are *not* readily available.

The laptops must be connected to the local network at Power Up *before* a user logs in. I have logged in and connected a laptop to WiFi and made sure "Make this connection available to other users" is checked. It will only connect after someone logs in.

Research provided workarounds for this that are based on older OS versions that use Network Manager.  I could not find any solutions for 20.04 that use the new NetPlan and .yaml configuration.  Has anyone figured out how to enable this on 20.04?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: [This should give you what you need](https://askubuntu.com/a/1100370/1222991), and it's still valid in all modern versions of Ubuntu Desktop 

Comment: Thank you Matigo, that worked!  I'm new here, can't figure out how to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: it is a comment not an answer ;-) please make your own answer and accept it + upvote it. It adds some points to your account.

Answer (score 0):

Matigo provided a link that held the solution -- thank you!

For others who may find this, these are the boiled down steps I did:

In Terminal, run:

***nmcli***

Will show the network adapters & info. Make note of the SSID of the WiFi you want to automatically run at bootup and the IP address assigned to it. Then run:

***nmcli connection modify YourSSIDNameHere connection.autoconnect-priority 10***

On another machine, start a continuous ping to the laptop, then:

***Reboot the laptop.***

When the laptop restarts, your pings should resume before anyone logs into it.